# How can I get Blender to import normals as normals and not bump?

Tags: import, normals, .fbx, bump

I have a set of FBX files that I am editing and cleaning up.  These meshes have normals textures, but when I import them, they read as bump maps, with the Height attribute pointed to the normals map.  This causes the meshes to look terrible, and so for each object I have to do the following in the materials section:

1. Change bump to normals
2. Change flat color to Image Map
3. Point the node to the normals map

This may not sound like a big deal, but I've had to do this hundreds of times. Is there a way to get Blender to recognize that these should be imported as normals, and if so, how do I do that?